# How to insert to a data into a table after deleting a row with the same primary key?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure to update a records in a separate table. For this task first of all I remove all the records relevant to that primary key. Then run a insert query. But when I do so I get an error in SQL Server.

Here is the stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[update_HS_HR_LANG]
    @appNo Int,
    @LCODE VARCHAR(30),
    @ABILITY int
AS
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM [HS_HR_LANG]
    WHERE App_no = @appNo
END
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [HS_HR_LANG] ([App_no], [lang_code], [ability_type])
    VALUES (@appNo, @LCODE, @ABILITY)
END
```

This is the error I get

> Must declare the scalar variable "@appNo"

Comment: Remove the `end begin` in the middle

Comment: @artm it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your stored procedure ends here:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[update_HS_HR_LANG]
@appNo Int,
@LCODE VARCHAR(30),
@ABILITY int

AS

BEGIN

DELETE 
FROM [HS_HR_LANG]
WHERE App_no=@appNo

END -- <-----HERE
```

You then access `@appNo` later on so you get the error.

Therefore, you should have this instead:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[update_HS_HR_LANG]
@appNo Int,
@LCODE VARCHAR(30),
@ABILITY int

AS

BEGIN -- <----- START

DELETE 
FROM [HS_HR_LANG]
WHERE App_no=@appNo

insert into [HS_HR_LANG]
([App_no]
,[lang_code]
,[ability_type])
 VALUES
       (@appNo,
        @LCODE,
        @ABILITY)
END  -- <----- END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[update_HS_HR_LANG]
 @appNo Int,
 @LCODE VARCHAR(30),
 @ABILITY int

 AS

 BEGIN --<--start begin from here and remove the begin,end in the middle---

 DELETE 
 FROM [HS_HR_LANG]
 WHERE App_no=@appNo

 insert into [HS_HR_LANG]
 ([App_no]
,[lang_code]
,[ability_type])
 VALUES
   (@appNo,
    @LCODE,
    @ABILITY)
    END  -- <---------
```